# Where can I read a list of Steam Play supported titles?

Tags: steam

I'm using Steam on Linux. Settings shows an option 'Enable [Steam Play](https://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1696055855739350561) for supported titles'. Where can I read a list of these games?

I found https://www.protondb.com/ which has compatibility information but doesn't distinguish officially supported titles from other titles.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go https://www.protondb.com/explore?page=0&selectedFilters=whitelisted&sort=playerCount

Also https://steamdb.info/app/891390/ which includes the precise Proton versions used for each game